# Returning each item in list in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
list = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']

for item in list:
    return item
```

My goal:

1st time running this function, I would want 0
2st time running this function, I would want 1
3rd time running this function, I would want 2
.
.
.
7th time running this function, I would want 6.

print (item) does this trick but is there a way to do it with return?

thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).  Try playing with `iterator = iter(my_list)` and then doing multiple `next(iterator)`.

Comment: Related: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator

Comment: @PatrickHaugh `.next()` removes the next item. If this is what OP wants, they may as well use `.pop()`. Otherwise, they need a counter for the function. Maybe what they are trying to do could be replaced with `enumerate(list)`?

Comment: @spikespaz No it doesn't? Calling `next(iterator)` will destructively consume the iterator, but the list will remain unchanged.  You can always just get another iterator with `iter(my_list)`.

Comment: What would you want for the 8th time running the function?

Comment: I would want to have the function returning the wanted value. At the 8th sequence, I would like it to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `next`:

```
>>> l = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']
>>> iter_ = iter(l)
>>> next(iter_)
'0'
>>> next(iter_)
'1'
>>> next(iter_)
'2'
>>>
```

Comment: Just want to know if there is a way to get the same effect by returning

Comment: @swpc it should work fine, unless you are calling `next` on a new iterator in each function call. You should be calling next on the `same` iterator each time, until you reach the `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a method called pop

Each time that you run list.pop(0), it pops the first element in the list, so if you run it multiple times it will returning each element one by one

```
>>> list = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']
>>> list.pop(0)
'0'
>>> list.pop(0)
'1'
>>> list.pop(0)
'2'
```

Comment: I was thinking about using the .pop but it removes the element as well. :(

Comment: you can create a copy of the array, otherwise you'll have to use a counter as mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter variable.

```
counter = 0
l = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']

def returnVal():
  global counter
  global l
  counter = (counter + 1) % len(l)
  return l[counter]

print(returnVal())
print(returnVal())
print(returnVal())
print(returnVal())
print(returnVal())
print(returnVal())
print(returnVal())
print(returnVal())
```

Working example: https://repl.it/@LukasBach/VoluminousFrozenHexadecimal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help you, you can get the next item by `.get_next()` and reset to the first item by `.reset()`. Just initialize the object with `Looper(items*)`, as you would with a list.

```
class Looper(list):
    _counter = -1

    def get_next(self):
        self._counter += 1
        return self[self._counter]

    def reset_counter(self):
        self._counter = -1
```

I didn't really know what to call it so for the sake of time just chose `Looper`.